# What's so hard about contradiction proofs w.r.t. primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, soft-question, alternative-proof, prime-gaps

I've always felt like there should be some relatively straightforward proofs by contradiction establishing theorems about prime distribution. Ideally they would exist for things like twin prime conjecture / infinitude of $x^2+1$ primes, but here, let's focus on a simpler case, already solved: Bertrand's conjecture.

Suppose we assert a prime gap larger than the prime it follows, i.e. $$\exists p_i \in \mathbb P : p_i < 2p_i<p_{i+1}.$$

Naïvely, I would think it should cause no end of problems, readily leading to absurd results which are easily digestible. I envision, for instance, a few simple steps from a Bertrand-breaking prime gap to demonstrating that that would imply some large even number is prime, or that there could only be finitely many primes, or some other catastrophic consequence. Since such an assertion seems so inimical to the overall structure of the primes, a problem thread to pull shouldn't be so difficult to locate.

(I know Erdős's proof of Bertrand is considered a gold standard of elegance, but that's neither here nor there, and is not an example of the the type of proof I attempted to describe above.)

So to reiterate,

**What is it about the primes that tends to render straightforward contradiction proofs so hard to come by?**

Why does such an impossible gap not cause things to break down in exploitable ways? Do the primes as a set "self-repair" their distribution so that the consequences of such assertions fade away over time rather than get amplified and cause cascading problems?

Any reasonably cogent explanation along these lines would be a suitable answer (even if the answer is ultimately "we don't know").

Comment: I have always felt that theorems about prime numbers are either elementary (in that there is a proof that the ancient Greeks could easily understand and appreciate) or highly non-elementary (in that it needs a modern graduate level number theory course or two to begin reading the simplest proof, or even just to understand the theorem itself). This might not be _entirely_ true. But I don't think I've met anyone who disagrees with the general sentiment.

Comment: (If I recall correctly, the proof that I've read, and would like to actually learn, of Bertrand's postulate arrives at a contradictory estimate of $\binom{2p}{p}$ from the assumption that that number has no prime factors above $p$. It could be a counterexample to my above claim, but I don't remember the details of the proof.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand's_postulate is a pretty good writeup of it. And you might be right, that may be as close to straightforward as things ever get, once you move beyond proofs of infinitude of the primes or the like. However, still doesn't answer *why* blowing holes in the distribution of the primes usually can't be traced to a problematic effect!

Comment: To adress the main question : The prime number theorem can be refined (Dussart's bounds) allowing to prove many important theorems about the distribution of the prime numbers. But when it comes to detect particular primes, it quickly becomes difficult. The only solved cases for functions $f(n)$ is $an+b$ with coprime $a$ and $b$ and the amazing case $a^2+b^4$ with integers $a,b$.

Comment: Also, no method is known to construct ANY huge not already known prime number efficiently. We can only sieve out the factors with trial division and apply a probable prime test. This is what is meant with "primes are random". Many people misinterprete this statement leading to a heavy disagreement.

Comment: Finally, the prime gaps fluctuate heavily. There is no known method to predict at least approximately the prime gap after some given prime. Large and small gaps occur apparently in a chaotic way and noone found yet a structure. Amazingly, we know that there are infinite many prime gaps not exceeding $246$.